# Change ListView layout to cells layout

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, catalog, xmlcatalog

I have a `ListView` in my Android app. The `ListView` supposed to be a catalog of items. Right now, it doesn't look very much like catalog, since it is shown as rows list.

Is there a way to create some sort of a table view with 3 vertical rows and as many horizontal rows as the items count in the catalog, and still use the same data which I'm using in the `ListView`? Also, how to change the cell layout to be shown well as a rectangle cell?

CellLayout.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/itemNameList"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/itemPriceList"
    android:layout_below="@+id/itemNameList"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/itemImageList"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
```

Comment: Pretty sure you want a GridView or RecyclerView with a GridLayoutManager. ListView will only ever do a single vertical stack of items.

Comment: Yes, but how can I change it, and still use my `BaseAdapter`?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it in a very easy method: I've just changed the type of the `ListView` to `GridView` and fixed the cell layout, so it will be shown vertically instead of horizontally.